# gcc Compling and linking object file and source file at the same time

Tags: css, linux, gcc, compilation

In a nutshell , the issue is I have some object file (say `a.o` , `b.o` ) and some source file (`f.c` and `g.c`)
I have to compile and link in a single step.

This is what I am doing but I don't think this is the write way atleast I should give something like `-l` or `-L` for linking

```
gcc -Wall -O0 -ggdb -fPIC  a.o b.o f.c g.c -o executable
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and state if your command works or not. If not, add details what exactly doesn't work. If you get an error message, please copy&paste it. Do you mean `-Wall -O0` (with uppercase W and O)? Please always copy&paste your code to the question instead of re-typing it. You need `-l` only if your program uses a library that is not linked by default, and `-L` if you use a library that is not located in the system's or compiler's default library directories.

Comment: Why does it have to be a single step?

Comment: @user16323802 You edited the typos but you din't tell us if the command works or not, and if not what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: My command is working but I had a doubt about using. C and. O file together is good practice or not @Bodo

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add all relevant information there instead of using comments for this purpose. If you don't have the source code for the .o files, this is OK. If you are working on a bigger project it might be better to individually compile all .c files to the resulting .o files and in a separate step link all .o files because this will be faster when only one (or a few) of the source files has changed.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct way, `-l` is used to link to a library (for example, the ptheads library needs `-lpthread`) and `-L` is used to add directories to the directories in which the linker looks for library files.

There is nothing wrong with compiling the software this way.
Most build systems build files one at a time in order to avoid having to rebuild the object file in case the source file was not modified and the object file still exists. If you are fine with rebuilding code, then your approach is perfectly valid.